# Отслеживание переходов по ссылкам php

Tags: php

Как отследить посредством php что пользователь перешел по внешней ссылке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант - все внешние ссылки пропускать через свой сервер.

ну например:

`<a href="http://example.com/redirect?url=http://another-site.com">`

и собстна, в скрипте, который будет по адресу /redirect - делать всё то, что вам захочется) ну и потом редиректить пользователя на тот сайт, куда он захотел)

Comment: а все понял, это получается уже get запрос:)
хм, я и не знал что у меня столько выбора буду пробывать все методы:)

Answer (score 1):

На стороне сервера это отследить нельзя. Можно следить на клиенте.
В ссылке указать не адрес перехода, а функцию JavaScript, которая отследит нажатие и осуществит переход:

```
function go(url){
    SendUrlToMyServer(url);
    location.href=url;
};

<a href="javascript:go('http://ya.ru')">
```

Comment: НЕ выводит ничего.

    <script>
    function go(url){
        SendUrlToMyServer(url);
        location.href=url;
    alert(url);

    };
    </script>
    <a href="javascript:go('http://ya.ru')">Click</a>

Comment: Наверно потому, что отсутствует функция SendUrlToMyServer, которую Вам надо написать самому. Внутри может быть например отправка данных на Ваш сервер средствами XHR.  
Для того, чтобы понять, почему тот или иной код не работает советую открывать в браузере консоль JavaScript.

Comment: ок, понял. то есть теперь я могу post-запрос сделать на сервер?

Answer (score 1):

Не можно а нужно. К примеру так:

```
var SendUrlToMyServer = function(url){
    $.post('/save/url',{url:url});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как настроить ответ сервера?
404 ошибка сервера через htaccess
Если Ваш сервер или CMS не настроены атоматически, то придётся это сделать Вам самим – добавьте в htaccess строчку:

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.site.ru/404.php

Теперь, когда пользователь введёт неверный адрес, то он будет направлен на этот адрес. Страница может располагаться где угодно, но мы для примера поместили ее в корне сайта: /404.php.
Взято с этого ресурса  https://web-optimizator.com/404-not-found/
и прекрасно работает у меня на всех сайтах!
Подправлено после вопроса ниже: Данный пример работает на переадресацию любых BAD запросов на 404 страницу, для полного счастья и возможности отследить кто куда нажал на вашем сайте можно перенаправить все запросы на какую то промежуточную страницу, там обработать все и отправить пользователя туда куда он должен был попасть.

Comment: отслеживание переходов по ссылкам можно осуществлять данным предложенным способом, сам искал ответ и нашел данное решение, так же был на форуме и видел актуальность данной проблемы для новичков и не очень,так что да это сообщение напрямую отвечает на поставленный вопрос "Отслеживание переходов по ссылка в php".  А пример настройки 404 страницы это лишь пример, настройте как угодно и следите за всеми переходами инкогнито ! то есть никак не обозначая это в ссылках или скриптах. ИМХО у каждого свое решение, это моё и я на нем не настаиваю!